# check if found specific record then find another record with the same group

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

Master table

```
PROBLEM_ID  PROBLEM            PGROUP
1           Other Hardware     Hardware
2           Error On hardware  Hardware
3           PM                 Hardware
4           Service            Maintenance
```

and a detail

```
TERM          PROBLEM            PROBLEM_ID
S1G166901     PM                    3
S1G166902     PM                    3
S1G166903     Service               4
S1G166902     Other on hardware     1
S1G166901     Service               4
S1G166901     Other Hardware        1
S1G166901     Error on Hardware     2
```

i need to query if `PROBLEM_ID` = '41' then find a `PROBLEM` that have `PGROUP` = 'Hardware'

like this

```
TERM          PROBLEM            PROBLEM_ID    PGROUP
S1G166901     PM                    3          Hardware
S1G166901     Other hardware        1          Hardware             
S1G166901     Error on hardware     2          Hardware
S1G166902     PM                    3          Hardware
S1G166902     Other Hardware        1          Hardware
```

i try to use Outer apply but it's return too much row

my specific result is if they're not contain `PROBLEM_ID` = '41' then will not show but if contain will show all problem with pgroup ='Hardware' by term

i try this

```
SELECT p.TERM, p.Problem_ID,p.problem, PGROUP
FROM Problem_log AS p 
CROSS APPLY ( 
            SELECT s.pgroup, s.problem_id 
            FROM problem AS s 
            WHERE   s.problem_id = p.problem_id AND PGROUP = 'Hardware'  )as s

            WHERE  exists (Select s.PGROUP,s.PROBLEM_ID 
            from PROBLEM_LOG 
            WHERE problem_log.PROBLEM_ID = '41'  GROUP BY term) 
            ORDER BY TERM
```

my sequence is 
- Select data from table problem_log for problem_ID = '41'

- if problem_ID = '41' then For each record check found other problem (Hardware only)

Comment: You just need to have INNER JOIN with Master table and use PGROUP in the select statement.

Comment: @PareshJ  my specific result is if they're not contain PM then will not show but if contain will show all problem with pgroup ='Hardware' by term, but if i use  inner join it's will show all right ? i just need if Problem = 'PM' is exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this query should work in your case.

```
Select DISTINCT  D.TERM, M.PROBLEM, M.PROBLEM_ID, M.PGROUP
From Problem M Inner Join Problem_log D
ON M.PROBLEM=D.PROBLEM
WHERE (D.TERM IN (Select TERM FROM Problem_log D1 Inner Join Problem M1
                  ON M1.PROBLEM=D1.PROBLEM
                  Where D1.PROBLEM_ID=D.PROBLEM_ID And 
                        M1.PGROUP='Hardware' AND D1.Problem='PM'))
ORDER BY TERM,PROBLEM
```

You can try this query on **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/475c9/14)**

Comment: I don't understand why the subquery is even necessary. In your fiddle I replaced the whole thing with just the PGROUP and Problem conditions. It gives me the same results. (Of course having the Problem text in both tables is probably a bad idea too.)

Comment: @shawnt00 look at my editing history I have also done that same thing before. but, it was not showing the correct result in OP's database. I don't know how but, it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use INNER JOIN with Master table to get PGROUP for each ProblemID

Check the below query:

```
SELECT D.TERM, D.PROBLEM, D.PROBLEM_ID, M.PGROUP
FROM Details D INNER JOIN Master M ON D.ProblemID = M.ProblemID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Details WHERE PRoblem = 'PM' AND TERM = D.TERM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
SELECT dt.Term, dt.Problem, dt.ProblemID
FROM DetailsTable dt
JOIN MasterTable mt ON dt.ProblemID = mt.ProblemID
JOIN MasterTable mt1 ON mt.PGroup = mt1.PGroup and mt1.Problem = 'PM'
ORDER BY dt.Term
```

Comment: your code nearly work, but It's still show a TERM that not contain 'PM' i try my own way before see your post it's remain the same result as your code